# Find maxima of segmented regions

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have 2 3D grayscale images of equal dimensions.

The first image (`img`) is the raw data of a 3D volume (obtained using a microscope) and contains various cells. [Example slice of raw 3d image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwnQn.jpg)

The second image (`imglab`) is a masked version of the raw image where each identified cell is filled with a single, unique value (i.e. cell 1 = all 1s, cell 2 = all 2s). All non cell regions are zeros. [Example slice of masked 3d image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOtI7.jpg)

I am now trying to find the coordinates of the maximum value of each cell from the raw data that corresponds to the labeled mask array.

Currently, I have a loop which is extremely inefficient. I suspect there is a way to setup multiple conditions using a single `np.where` call, but I can't figure out how to do this. The current `for` loop method is below:

```
coordinates = []
for i in range(1, int(imglab.max())): # Number of cells = max value of label image
    max_val = np.max(img[imglab == i])
    max_coord = np.where((img == max_val) & (imglab == i))
    coordinates.append(max_coord)
```

Comment: Use `regionprops`: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops

Answer (score 0):

When it is difficult to find a way of coding efficient and compatible with numpy, but when the code with `for` loops is trivial, you can use `njit`from `numba`.

It works best to process flat arrays, so first let's write a function in numba that does what you ask but in 1d:

```
from numba import njit, int64

@njit
def fast_max_flat(img_flat, imglab_flat):
    n_cells =int(imglab_flat.max())  # number of cells
    max_values = np.full(n_cells, - np.inf)  # stores the n_cells max values seen so far
    max_coords = np.zeros(n_cells, dtype=int64)  # stores the corresponding coordinate
    n_pixels = len(img)
    for i in range(n_pixels):
        label = imglab_flat[i]
        value = img_flat[i]
        if max_values[label] < value:
            max_values[label] = value
            max_coords[label] = i
    return max_coords
```

And then write a python wrapper that ravels the array, applies the previous function, and retrieves the coordinates as a list:

```
def wrapper(img, imglab):
    dim = img.shape
    coords = fast_max_flat(img.ravel(), imglab.ravel())
    return [np.unravel_index(coord, dim) for coord in coords]
```

On my machine, with a `100 x 100 x 100` image of 3 cells, this is ~50 times faster than your method.